# Why is the Plaid.create func not returning any output?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, plaid

I am using Flask to try and get the Plaid Link to come up for my user to login to.

I am trying to figure out why I can see no console logs being outputted from the`Plaid.create` func that is being called on button click. It is hard to debug since it is not giving me much output to work with.

Here is my simple html page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Index</title>
  
  <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
  <script>
    async function login()
    {
      console.log("Initiating login!")
      const response = await fetch("/create_link_token") # Call to endpoint implemented in Flask
      const {link_token} = await response.json()
      console.log(link_token)
      console.log("before the link handler")
      const handler = Plaid.create
      ({
        token: await link_token,
        onSuccess: async (public_token, metadata) => {
          console.log(public_token);
          console.log(metadata);
          console.log("/token_exchange/"+public_token)
          token = await fetch("/token_exchange/"+public_token)
          console.log(token)
        },
        onExit: (err, metadata) => {
          console.log(err);
          console.log(metadata)
        },
        onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {
          console.log(eventName);
          console.log(metadata);
        },
      });
      console.log("Done!")
    }
  </script>
</head>

  <body>
    <h1 style="color: blue">Hello, World!</h1>
    <p>This is an HTML file served up by Flask</p>
    <form>
      <input type="button" onclick="login()" value="Login" />
  </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Here is the console output

```
Initiating login! 
link-development-24e61667-d41f-4ca3-b936-b7b995054646
before the link handler
Done!
```

So it seems to me that the create function is not finishing or silently failing, as I should have the Plaid Link come up to continue the auth flow as far as I understand. However, it doesn't even seem to be continuing to the point of fetching my route or even hitting any of the other callbacks.

Thanks for any help and clarification you may be able to provide. Please let me know if I have any misunderstanding in JS as well.

Answer (score 0):

`link_token` is just a string, not a promise, so it doesn't need to be `await`ed.  Likewise, the callback signature of onSuccess is defined as `onSuccess: function (publicToken, metadata)` and it needs to stay that way in order to work.

Here's some simple code that does work correctly, if it helps at all:

```
<!DOCHTML html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>

<title> Plaid demo app</title>

</head>

<body>
  <button id="link-button">Link account</button>

  <script>

  async function createPlaid() {

    const linkToken = await $.get('/create-link-token');

    const handler = Plaid.create({
      token: linkToken,
      onSuccess: function (publicToken, metadata) {
        fetch('/exchange-token', {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify({ publicToken}),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          }
        });
      }
  })

  $("#link-button").on("click", function (e) {
    handler.open();
  })
}

createPlaid();

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```